# Scala: if inside match case

Tags: scala, if-statement, functional-programming

Is there any way to put a if inside a match case in scala?

Something like this:

```
def createSchedules(listTask: List[TaskOrder], physicalResources: List[Physical], humanResources: List[Human], previousTime: Duration): List[TaskSchedule] = listTask match {
    case TaskOrder(id, time, physicalRes, order) :: t =>
      val taskScheduleHumanResources = setHumanResources(physicalRes, humanResources)
      if (physicalRes != null) 
        new TaskSchedule(
          order, 
          order.getProduct(), 
          Task(id, time, physicalRes), 
          physicalRes, 
          taskScheduleHumanResources, 
          order.quantity, 
          previousTime, 
          previousTime + time) :: createSchedules(t, physicalRes, humanResources, previousTime + time)
    case Nil => Nil
  }
```

Doing that I get an error saying:

> type mismatch; found : Unit required: List[Objects.TaskSchedule]

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: What do you do when `physicalRes` is `null`?

Comment: I don't create a new TaskSchedule. But I cannot also return null, otherwise I would get a nullPointerException later in the execution of the application.

Comment: Then you need to add an `else Nil`. Do you populate `physicalRes` inside `setHumanResources`?

Comment: No, I don't. But your solution worked, it was easier than I thoguht. Thank you. Write an answer if you want, so I can accept it.

Comment: Note that your code is not tail-recursive and will throw `StackOverflowError` for `listTask` with big number of elements. Make a habit to add `@annotation.tailrec` for all suspicious functions -- that forces compiler to check necessary conditions and fail compilation if goal cannot be achieved.

Comment: Just to confirm, do you want to stop processing after the first `null`? I.e., if the input is `List(taskOrder1, null, taskOrder3)`, should the output be `List(taskSchedule1)`? Or `List(taskSchedule1, taskSchedule3)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the compiler is infering `Unit` is that you don't have an `else` clause, which means you don't return a value in case `physicalRes` is null.

You need to add an `else` clause to your code:

```
case TaskOrder(id, time, physicalRes, order) :: t => 
  val taskScheduleHumanResources = setHumanResources(physicalRes, humanResources)
  if (physicalRes != null) // stuff
  else createSchedules(t, physicalRes, humanResources, previousTime + time)
```

You can use `collect` to only select the desire elements:

```
val res: List[TaskSchedule] = listTask.collect {
   case order if order.physicalRes != null => new TaskSchedule(...)
}
```

Or you can also fold over the collection and only accumulate when you find non-empty `physicalRes`:

```
val res: List[TaskSchedule] = listTask.foldLeft(List.empty[TaskOrder]) {
  case (acc, order) => 
    if (order.physicalRes != null) {
       new TaskSchedule(...) :: acc
    } else acc
}
```

Comment: Your foldLeft solution will reverse the ordering of the items. This may or may not matter in this case, but I thought I ought to point it out.

Comment: @JackLeow The original solution already implies that OP doesn't care about order.

Comment: I am not sure how you arrived at that conclusion? Could you clarify? The code seems to maintain order, and nowhere does he say he does not care about order.

Comment: @JackLeow He's prepending each newly created `TaskSchedule` while recursing the existing list.

Comment: Are you implying that his approach reverses the list? It does not. Read the code carefully. I can provide you with an example you can paste in the REPL if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
    def createSchedules(listTask: List[TaskOrder],
                        physicalResources: List[Physical],
                        humanResources: List[Human],
                        previousTime: Duration): List[TaskSchedule] = listTask match {
      case TaskOrder(id, time, physicalRes, order) :: t =>{
        val taskScheduleHumanResources = setHumanResources(physicalRes, humanResources);
        if(physicalRes != null) 
          new TaskSchedule(order, order.getProduct(), Task(id, time, physicalRes), physicalRes, taskScheduleHumanResources, order.quantity, previousTime, previousTime + time):: createSchedules(t, physicalRes, humanResources, previousTime + time)
        else 
          Nil
      }
      case Nil => Nil
    }
  }
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the compiler tries to infer type of the `if` expression (it would try and find the first common super-type shared by the `if` and `else`). Given the lack of an `else`, it goes with `Unit`, hence the error you were receiving.

If I understand what you are trying to do, `collect`ing seems the easiest way to accomplish that:

```
def createSchedules(listTask: List[TaskOrder], physicalResources: List[Physical], humanResources: List[Human], previousTime: Duration): List[TaskSchedule] =
  listTask.collect {
    case TaskOrder(id, time, physicalRes, order) if physicalRes != null =>
      val taskScheduleHumanResources = setHumanResources(physicalRes, humanResources)
      new TaskSchedule(
        order, 
        order.getProduct(), 
        Task(id, time, physicalRes), 
        physicalRes, 
        taskScheduleHumanResources, 
        order.quantity, 
        previousTime, 
        previousTime + time
      )
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't support the requirement that when `physicalRes` is null, you still invoke `setHumanResources`.